# DGI 8000 GIVES 6985 IN EMV

Tags: personalization, emv, mastercard

Hello i am trying to personalize a MCHIP card and while sending store data command for DGI -8000 , getting error 6985.

```
     My kmc was - 40414243...4f, then i calualate 3 static keys and 3    session keys (S-ENC, S-MAC, S-DEK),
 I ENCRYPT ANY 3, 16 BYTE DATA WITH S-DEK KEY IN ECB MODE (TESTING NO REAL KEY REQUIRE) AND SEND STORE DATA 
    COMMAND
```

LIKE:-

```
Transmit: 80 E2 60 07 33    []
  80 00 30 7C F4 EE 30 32 F8 F8 FB 0F C9 CC 8B 3D    ..0...02...å...=
  24 DC 32 7C F4 EE 30 32 F8 F8 FB 0F C9 CC 8B 3D    ¤.2...02...å...=
  24 DC 32 7C F4 EE 30 32 F8 F8 FB 0F C9 CC 8B 3D    ¤.2...02...å...=
  24 DC 32                                           ¤.2
Card answered: 69 85
```

could anybody tell me where i am doing mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that there was some other command I have to send before DGI - 8000 . Commands like put key ..

When I did this this error removed

Comment: Actually different Chip have fixed rule to personalize card. Here it was necessary to load new keys before sending SFI, DGI to card. I found this written in manual of chip.